# Possible as a workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I want to create a workflow for SharePoint Online with SharePoint Designer 2013. Since I am new to the workflow stuff I wanted to ask if the following workflow is possible in SahrePoint Online. It should do the following:

1. When there goes a document (which is a pdf) into a specific library then a mail get send out to a specific person and the docoument gets an entry into an excel file (or something else that tracks the documents in the library) based on its name (the name should get parsed)
2. This person has to sign it (in the new acrobat reader you can sign the documents with a "stamp")
3. When the person signed the document someone gets informed about it (through mail)

Cheers